# PostCatcher Equivalent For Https?

Tags: https

I have been using [postcatcher.in](http://postcatcher.in) to test my HTTP post requests. But, I have no been able to find an equivalent service which supports HTTPS. Does anyone knows of something like that?

Answer (score 0):

[Beeceptor](https://Beeceptor.com) - can help you. It is real-time and supports HTTPs.

- Request payload inspection
- Mocking the response when a request path matches

---

*(Disclaimer: I am the author and developed this as a need to proxy requests to an HTTP endpoint and still want to mock a few requests)*